# Undecorated Microsoft Symbol: SomeClass::`vftable'{for `Foo::Bar'}

Tags: windows, symbols, dbghelp

I'm using `UnDecorateSymbolNameW` from dbghelp to un-decorate Microsoft symbol names. When undecorating with `UNDNAME_COMPLETE`, the symbol name can sometimes have, what I understand to be, some compiler appended information to it. For example a vftable symbol can sometimes have a curly bracket block containing a `for` keyword followed by a class/interface name, e.g.

> SomeClass::'vftable'{for 'Foo::Bar'}

Can anybody inform me as to what the `"{for 'Foo::Bar'}"` portion of the name means?

Additionally does anybody know of some documentation about this so I can read up as I can't find anything.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You are not going to find this documented, these are compiler implementation details that are subject to change.  A class can have more than one v-table due to multiple inheritance.  The postfix ensures their symbols are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `SomeClass` uses multiple inheritance, and it has multiple base classes with virtual methods. Therefore, `SomeClass` needs multiple vtables (one for each base class with virtual methods). The `{for 'Foo::Bar'}` tells you which vtable you have. In this case, it is the vtable for the `Foo::Bar` base class.

(This should have been self-evident from the name.)

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed this does make sense when you spell it out. Shame there is no documentation for this stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: This is all compiler-internal stuff. Compiler-internal stuff tends not to be documented because it can change at any time.

Comment: Fair enough, i'm trying to parse as much info from symbols as possible to generate a meta model for something, so a spec on this stuff is interesting to me. But I understand why a formal spec/documentation is not available.

Comment: Indeed, earlier versions of the compiler didn't say `{for 'Foo::Bar'}` - it just gave every vtable the same name. Who knows, future versions of the compiler may decorate vtables differently.